# How to collapse/expand only a single button in Angular 6

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get my code to have rows of collapsible buttons, but whenever I load into the page, all the buttons are expanded, and if I click any button, they all expand/collapse.

**HTML**

```
<div id="accordion" *ngFor="let project of projects">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#projectList" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                    {{project.projectName}}
                </button>
            </h5>
        </div>

        <div id="projectList" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
            <div class="card-body">
                {{project.projectDescription}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What do I need to change in order to get the buttons to only expand/collapse for the button I click?

Comment: can you give demo in plunker https://plnkr.co/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of multiple ids that are the same `projectList` which is inside the `ngFor` loop.

To fix this you would need to index it on your `ngFor`

```
*ngFor="let project of projects; let i = index"
```

Then you can make your ids a bit different by appending the index value (ex. `projectList-1`...etc), also make sure you do the same for `data-target`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using the same id for multiple ngFor instances..try removing the id
or give different id to each ngFor instances